# Prevent ASP.NET site files from being cached

Tags: asp.net, caching, browser-cache

We have ASP.NET forms website. For production we use bundling so no problem with scripts being cached.

For test environment we would like to keep all scripts unbundled but we also want to make sure they are not cached in user's browsers.

Is there web.config setting we can use to force IIS send all files with no cache header? Or something like this which will prevent debug compile from caching?

Comment: What bundling library do you use?

Comment: System.Web.Optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Web.Debug.config, add the following:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store" />
                <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
                <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The following configuration adds the necessary HTTP headers, for disabling client side caching. This will only apply to a debug build, since this configuration only exists in Web.Debug.config.

An in-depth explanation of the headers can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/234067).

Comment: Will it cover css and js files as well?

Comment: Yes, they should apply to every request.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tags in the head section

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

and also you can add the `?` symbol and add a variable at the end of the `src` attribute, this forces the browser to reload the source

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.11.2.min.js?v=1.0"></script>
```

it also apply to style sheets

Comment: Yes, but that is manual work every time. Not feasible. I was wondering if it can be done